# How can I find the center of a buldge for a curved line?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

The result should be around X=2500.

[image: Curved Line]

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by the center of the buldge?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, for example, the point where the distance from the straight line is greatest?

Comment: yes! that would definitely fit my definition of "buldge."

Comment: Then you can define a function of $x$ which is the distance to the curve.  You can either use vertical distance or the distance perpendicular to the line.  As you say, you can take a polynomial approximation to the curve, then compute the distance, take the derivative, set to zero, etc.  Finding the tangent line requires taking the derivative of the curve, which is quite prone to error if there is any noise in the data.  You could also just compute the distance from the data points to the blue line and find the maximum.